# Using an interface within a struct in Go

Tags: interface, struct, go

In trying to understand Go, I ran into this piece of code in `websocket.go` (snipped):

```
type frameHandler interface {
    HandleFrame(frame frameReader) (r frameReader, err error)
    WriteClose(status int) (err error)
}

// Conn represents a WebSocket connection.
type Conn struct {
    config  *Config
    request *http.Request
    .
    .
    frameHandler
    PayloadType        byte
    defaultCloseStatus int
}
```

In the Conn type the `frameHandler` stands there all alone? An interface without a name?
Later on in the code they even try check if the poor interface is nil:

```
Conn(a).frameHandler == nil
```

My own guess is that the `frameHandler` within the struct is a type which matches the frameHandler interface, and on top of that will have the name `frameHandler`. Is this correct? Hehe, fun language anyhow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line:

```
    frameHandler
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```
    frameHandler frameHandler
```

in that `frameHandler` is both the *name* of the field and its *type*. In addition, it adds all the fields and methods of the `frameHandler` to the `Conn`, so if `conn` is a `Conn`, then `conn.WriteClose(0)` means `conn.frameHandler.WriteClose(0)`.

As [the Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Struct_types) puts it:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an *anonymous field* (colloquially called an embedded field). Such a field type must be specified as a type name `T` or as a pointer to a non-interface type name `*T`, and `T` itself may not be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field name.
>
> ```
> // A struct with four anonymous fields of type T1, *T2, P.T3 and *P.T4
> struct {
>     T1        // field name is T1
>     *T2       // field name is T2
>     P.T3      // field name is T3
>     *P.T4     // field name is T4
>     x, y int  // field names are x and y
> }
> ```
>
> The following declaration is illegal because field names must be unique in a struct type:
>
> ```
> struct {
>     T         // conflicts with anonymous field *T and *P.T
>     *T        // conflicts with anonymous field T and *P.T
>     *P.T      // conflicts with anonymous field T and *T
> }
> ```
>
> Fields and methods (§Method declarations) of an anonymous field are promoted to be ordinary fields and methods of the struct (§Selectors). The following rules apply for a struct type named `S` and a type named `T`:
>
> - If `S` contains an anonymous field `T`, the
>             method set of `S` includes the
>             method set of `T`.
> - If `S` contains an anonymous field `*T`, the
>             method set of `S` includes the method set of `*T`
>             (which itself includes the method set of `T`).
> - If `S` contains an anonymous field `T` or
>             `*T`, the method set of `*S` includes the
>             method set of `*T` (which itself includes the method
>             set of `T`).
>
> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal *tag*, which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration. The tags are made visible through a reflection interface but are otherwise ignored.
>
> ```
> // A struct corresponding to the TimeStamp protocol buffer.
> // The tag strings define the protocol buffer field numbers.
> struct {
>     microsec  uint64 "field 1"
>     serverIP6 uint64 "field 2"
>     process   string "field 3"
> }
> ```

Comment: Okay, then it was as I suspected. Can you do like that with types as well? `myInt` would be equal to `myInt myInt`? Ah! Your addition just answered my second thought.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The language surely has it its fun ways.

Comment: Also note that the methods of frameHandler are automatically also methods of Conn.

Comment: @AnschelSchaffer-Cohen: Good point. My answer is not really accurate in saying that those two forms are equivalent, since the first does more than the second. I'll see about editing it.